# Variable does not exist Salesforce Apex

Tags: apex, soql

I have this apex code:

```java
trigger AssignLetter on Opportunity (Before insert) {
    for(Opportunity opp: Trigger.New){
        Set<String> selectedValues = new Set<String>();
        for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
            SELECT Letter__c FROM Opportunity GROUP BY Letter__c
        ]) selectedValues.add((String)aggregate.get('Letter__c'));
        
        List<String> unselectedValues = new List<String>();
        for (PicklistEntry entry : Opportunity.Letter__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues())
            if (!selectedValues.contains(entry.getValue()))
                unselectedValues.add(entry.getValue());
        
            String letter = [SELECT Letter__c
                        FROM Opportunity
                        WHERE Letter__c != NULL
                        GROUP BY Letter__c
                        Order By Count(Id), Letter__c
                        LIMIT 1][0].Letter__c;
        
        if(unselectedValues != null && !unselectedValues.isEmpty()){
            opp.Letter__c = unselectedValues[0];
        }
        else {
            opp.Letter__c = letter;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to assign a picklist value that is a string to the variable letter. For some reason the console has an error saying that variable 'Letter__c' does not exist.
What can be the problem?

Comment: The query always returns a list. Try `[SELECT ...][0].Letter__c;` to get the letter from the first (and only) result.

Comment: BTW, when asking a question, please always include the exact error and, if possible, identify the specific line of code that causes the error.

Comment: @PhilW it shows the same error

Comment: Your query returns a List of AggregateResult, not a list of Opportunity.

Comment: I uploaded the full code now.

Comment: As pointed out by Felix, you need to access the value as needed for an aggregate query.

Comment: Thank you guys I solved it! I did not know about the class being different when using Aggregate Functions.